# Astronomical data bases express spectra in flux density, e.g. ergs/s/cm2/Angstrom( or Hz) how can I calculate the flux, i.e. ergs/s/cm2?

Tags: light, spectra, flux

I have light spectral data from astronomy data bases in flux density (flux/Angstrom or flux/Hz) and would like to calculate the flux. How can I calculate the flux from the flux density?

Comment: Hi Jim, do you know what the difference is between the two. I mean, what they describe, physically? Also, since the answer involves a filter, or some other way to limit a wavelength interval, can you provide a little more information (preferably also including how you've tried to find the answer yourself)?

Comment: The flux is simply the flux density integrated over some range of wavelengths or frequencies. (Basic dimensional analysis would indicate that, for example, flux = (flux/Angstrom) $\times# Angstrom.)

Comment: I have done a lot of reading and internet searching including books devoted to astronomical spectroscopy such as Planet, Stars and Stellar Systems Vol 2, as well as the help desk of the NED/caltech website. What I really need is the ability to calculate from the spectra the flux at particular wavelengths. For example, the spectrum of 3C 273 has the following values at 1153.32 A the Intensity is 6.4776e-13 [erg/cm^2/s/A]. Is the flux this value multiplied by 452.24 A which is the range over which the spectra is recorded?